# load variables from .ts in html in the middle of some method

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm in situation where I need to refresh html file in the middle of function in typescript file, how can I do this? Is it possible?, any builded function in angular? Thank you very much on help

Comment: please provide some sample code, what you have tried. You seem to use angular, than you should try reading the docs for routing, with routing you can change the rendered Dom and also keep your current state

Comment: I have not all the information, maybe you can try :
 setTimeout(() => {
    the code that need to refresh... 
  }, 0);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you just want to reload

```
window.location.reload();
```